# How would I go about solving this long equation for the variable $j$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$$
\frac{\left(
    \sqrt[3]{
     d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2 + \sqrt{\left(d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{3} × \left(\left(\frac{j}{2}\right) × \left(\frac{j}{s}\right)\right)^2\right)^3}
    }
  + \sqrt[3]{
     d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2 - \sqrt{\left(d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{3} × \left(\left(\frac{j}{2}\right) × \left(\frac{j}{s}\right)\right)^2\right)^3}
    }
  - \left(\left(\frac{j}{2}\right) × \left(\frac{j}{s}\right)\right)
\right)}{j}\\ - \frac{j}{s} - \frac{s}{c} = 0
$$

I want to solve it for the variable $j$. Based on other results in the project, I'm hoping to get an expression along the lines of

$$
j = \sqrt{ A^2 + Z_0 \sqrt[3]{B + \sqrt{B^2 + C^3}} + Z_0 \sqrt[3]{B - \sqrt{B^2 + C^3}}} + \sqrt{A^2 + Z_1 \sqrt[3]{B + \sqrt{B^2 + C^3}} + Z_2 \sqrt[3]{B - \sqrt{B^2 + C^3}}} + \sqrt{A^2 + Z_2 \sqrt[3]{B + \sqrt{B^2 + C^3}} + Z_1 \sqrt[3]{B - \sqrt{B^2 + C^3}}} - 3 A
$$

where the $Z_i$ variables are the three cube roots (one real and a pair of complex conjugates) of some real integer, and the $A$, $B$, and $C$ variables are some combinations of the $c$, $d$, and $s$ variables from my starting equation (with some rational exponents and fractions mixed in). I have no guarantee that the result will be in that exact format, but I would be surprised if it weren't at least similar.

Ordinarily what I'd do for this kind of problem (and have done multiple times in this project) is plug it into WolframAlpha, but in this specific case WolframAlpha just gives up. I tried using WolframScript with the command `Solve[((d * (j/2)^2 + ((d * (j/2)^2)^2 - (1/3 * (((j/2) * (j/s)))^2)^3)^(1/2))^(1/3) + (d * (j/2)^2 - ((d * (j/2)^2)^2 - (1/3 * (((j/2) * (j/s)))^2)^3)^(1/2))^(1/3) - ((j/2) * (j/s)))/j - j/s - s/c == 0, j]`, but it's been spinning for over seventeen hours with no solution yet.

It's been many years since my algebra classes, and I'm not sure how to approach this without the help of computers. The multiple nested radicals are really throwing me off. Trying to get rid of them by cubing/squaring seems to only create more radicals, as they don't all cancel out each time.

Can someone help me with the algebra here? Or alternatively, suggest a free computer algebra system that might succeed where WolframAlpha gives up (or a better way to phrase my input for WolframAlpha/WolframScript)?

I've been able to get the equation to this point on my own:

$$
   \sqrt[3]{
    \frac{1}{4} × \frac{d}{j} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{4} × \frac{d}{j}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{3} × \left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{j}{s}\right)^2\right)^3}
   }
 + \sqrt[3]{
    \frac{1}{4} × \frac{d}{j} - \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{4} × \frac{d}{j}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{3} × \left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{j}{s}\right)^2\right)^3}
   }
 = \frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}
$$

But as I said above, I get stuck trying to eliminate the radicals. If I set the $\left(\frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}\right)$ on the right hand side equal to zero so I'm left with only the two cube-root terms I can move one to the right hand side, cube both sides, and simplify to get $\frac{d}{j} = 0$, but that doesn't seem at all helpful because $\left(\frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}\right)$ is ***not*** equal to zero for almost all values of $c$, $s$, and $j$.

Comment: This looks *like* the [Cardano formula for a cubic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cardano_formula#:~:text=In%20the%20Cardano%20formula%2C%20p,4%2Bp327).

Comment: @TymaGaidash You're right. My equation is *exactly* the Cardano formula for a cubic where $x = \frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}$, $p = -\left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{j}{s}\right)^2$, and $q = -\left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{d}{j}\right)$. I'm not sure what to do with this information, though... I can't work on this more at this exact moment, but I'll think on it over the next few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TymaGaidash pointed out that my equation is in the format of the [Cardano formula for finding the roots of the general cubic equation over the field of complex numbers](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cardano_formula). Given the cubic equation $x^3 + p × x + q = 0$, the Cardano formula is:

$$
x = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{p}{3}\right)^3}} + \sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{p}{3}\right)^3}}
$$

Setting $p = -\left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{j}{s}\right)^2$, $q = -\left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{d}{j}\right)$, and $x = \left(\frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}\right)$ in the Cardano formula gives my equation after dividing out the $j$ in the denominator of the fraction term with the radicals. That implies that my equation is connected to the equation

$$
\left(\frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}\right)^3 - \left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{j}{s}\right)^2 × \left(\frac{3}{2} × \frac{j}{s} + \frac{s}{c}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} × \frac{d}{j}\right) = 0
$$

Expanding that, we get

$$
(6 × c^3) × j^4 + (13 × c^2 × s^2) × j^3 + (9 × c × s^4) × j^2 + (2 × s^6) × j - c^3 × s^3 × d = 0
$$

WolframAlpha actually returns results when asked to solve that for $j$, and while the results are messily formatted, one of them checks out as the answer I want:

`j = 1/2 sqrt((25 s^4)/(144 c^2) + (sqrt(455625 c^14 d^2 s^14 - 4 (3 c^2 s^8 - 72 c^6 d s^3)^3) - 675 c^7 d s^7)^(1/3)/(18 2^(1/3) c^3) + (c^2 s^8 - 24 c^6 d s^3)/(3 2^(2/3) c^3 (sqrt(455625 c^14 d^2 s^14 - 4 (3 c^2 s^8 - 72 c^6 d s^3)^3) - 675 c^7 d s^7)^(1/3))) + 1/2 sqrt((25 s^4)/(72 c^2) - (sqrt(455625 c^14 d^2 s^14 - 4 (3 c^2 s^8 - 72 c^6 d s^3)^3) - 675 c^7 d s^7)^(1/3)/(18 2^(1/3) c^3) - (c^2 s^8 - 24 c^6 d s^3)/(3 2^(2/3) c^3 (sqrt(455625 c^14 d^2 s^14 - 4 (3 c^2 s^8 - 72 c^6 d s^3)^3) - 675 c^7 d s^7)^(1/3)) + (35 s^6)/(864 c^3 sqrt((25 s^4)/(144 c^2) + (sqrt(455625 c^14 d^2 s^14 - 4 (3 c^2 s^8 - 72 c^6 d s^3)^3) - 675 c^7 d s^7)^(1/3)/(18 2^(1/3) c^3) + (c^2 s^8 - 24 c^6 d s^3)/(3 2^(2/3) c^3 (sqrt(455625 c^14 d^2 s^14 - 4 (3 c^2 s^8 - 72 c^6 d s^3)^3) - 675 c^7 d s^7)^(1/3))))) - (13 s^2)/(24 c)`

After chugging through the algebra, I've gotten it reduced to

$$
j = \sqrt{\frac{25}{144} X^2 +             \left(-2\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y + Z} +             \left(-2\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y - Z}}
  + \sqrt{\frac{25}{144} X^2 + \left(1 + \sqrt{3} i\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y + Z} + \left(1 - \sqrt{3} i\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y - Z}}
  + \sqrt{\frac{25}{144} X^2 + \left(1 - \sqrt{3} i\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y + Z} + \left(1 + \sqrt{3} i\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y - Z}}
  - \frac{13}{12} X
$$

where $X = \left(\frac{s}{2} × \frac{s}{c}\right)$, $Y = \left(d × \left(\frac{s}{3}\right)^3\right)$, $Z = \sqrt{\left(\frac{25}{2048} X^2 Y\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{432} X^4 - \frac{3}{32} Y\right)^3}$, and $i$ is the imaginary unit.